# Spring Boot: "Logback configuration error detected" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jar

I am using aan external library (jar file from another project) and I added that Jar file (artifact) from Dependencies tab in the Project Structure ~ Modules section.

However, when I run my project, I get the following error. I am not sure what I am missing, but I think I also need to add some extra  reference or library frokm the other project. Any idea?

Note that I created the artifact as mentioned on https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/hello-world/packaging-the-application/ . However, as that project is a Java8 project, I just added the module without starter class.

On the other hand, I added jar file to the project as mentioned on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-external-jar-file-to-an-intellij-idea-project/.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59219', transport: 'socket'
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:logback-default.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender[GELF_UDP] - Unknown GELF server hostname:udp:LOG_ENDPOINT_IP_IS_UNDEFINED java.net.UnknownHostException: LOG_ENDPOINT_IP_IS_UNDEFINED: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at nl.gerimedica.documents.GmDocumentsApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:16)
2022-10-03 11:06:42.723 ERROR 21530 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Comment: Downed Voters: Why did you vote down?

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle for building project?

Comment: Thanks for reply, what do you mean? I have maven but when I run mvn install or mvn clean install, I get errors even I use Toggle offline mode. ANy idea?

Comment: I use Maven by the way

Comment: Perhaps consider adding you jar files to maven, not via modules section of idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875/878241 . May be this is not a problem, and there is problem with logback, not sure.